# Php: Display something if First Record is Reached

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database where it has 10+ records:

```
Accid    |    Firstname    |    Lastname
1.              John                  Marshall
2.              Sherlock            Holmes
3.              Random            Dude
...
```

I'd display this using echo on php but with AJAX... it first loads up 5 users, and when the user has scrolled at the bottom of the page, it will load another 5 on the list (it adds the Offset's value +=5). Here's my display code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY lastname DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

While($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc) {
    echo $row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname']."<br/>";
 }
```

This list could be very long if I have 100 users let's say. 
Whenever the user scrolls at the bottom, another 5 users pops up. Now, if I reached the end of the whole records in the USERS database, I'd like to display something like - "End of User List"

How can I achieve this?

**Jquery Code**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "getusers.php",
   data: {
      'offset': 4
   },
success: function(data){
   $('#displayusers').append(data);
}
});
```

Comment: in the first call, provide the total users count.
Then, before making the AJAX call, see if the total is met, do not make the AJAX call and print out the "End of User List"

Comment: What type of JS are you using? Vanilla JS? jQuery? Angular? It matters!

Comment: @Babydead jquery

Comment: @Babydead I've updated my question

Comment: I would recommend you send it back as a JSON object so you can get the object length and such things... I will put an example into my answer, but for now I've answered how you could solve this "the simple way"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to disagree with @PressingOnAlways answer.

You can just send back a different response from PHP and check it in javascript.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY lastname DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
  die("last");
}

While($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc) {
    echo $row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname']."<br/>";
 }
```

Now you can just check it in javascript:

```
if(response == "last"){
  mydiv.append('This is the end');
}
```

---

Now, I would like to show you *my way of doing things*, which (imo) is a lot cleaner:

### First, your ajax calls

We're going to make sure our data will be in json format automatically from now on:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "getusers.php",
    cache: false,
    data: {'offset': 4},
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(json){

    if(json.hasOwnProperty("last"){
      //No more results
      //do your thang;
      return false;
    }

    if(getLength(json) < 5){
      //Smaller then 5, must have hit the last. Do your thang;
      return false;
    }

    //It came here, so it's all good. Go on
    $('#displayusers').append(data);
  });
```

### Secondly: Your PHP side

It's never a good plan to echo html over AJAX. It's way more efficient (takes up less servertime + sends smaller amounts of data over the internet highway) than doing it in PHP.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY lastname DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
$lastResponse = array("last" => "last");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
  //Always send back json or it'll give you an error
  die(json_encode($lastResponse));
}

$return = array();

While($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc) {
    $return[] = $row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname'];
 }

echo json_encode($return);
```

### Third: A js function to check the arrayLength

```
//Checks the length of a json object or array
//Returns false if length is 0 or unable to check it
function getLength(obj) {
  if (typeof obj == 'undefined') {
    return false;
  }
  var l = 0;
  if (typeof obj == 'object') {
    l = Object.keys(obj).length;
  }
  else {
    l = obj.length;
  }
  return (l == 0 ? false : l);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this code... but I just don't understand , the IF is just checking if there are any users registered, therefor when the database is empty it would return to "last" right? Since num_rows will equal to 0. But if there are records in the database, wouldn't it skip the IF statement since the num_rows is not equal to zero?

Comment: You put an offset in your code. If the offset is bigger than there are records, it won't return any. num_rows checks how many records came back from your query, not how many there are in the database. So the query will return 0 :) 

So yeah, if it returns records, it will skip the if statement since it's not the last

Answer (score 0):

The best place to implement this feature would be on the JS client side. Since your PHP script has no way of knowing if it is the end of the list or not, you need to do this on the client. The JS code should check if the results returned from your php script is less than 5, if so, the "End of User List" should be printed.

Comment: It would be fine, because the next query would return 0 results and you can print it then.

Comment: My jscode is a quite simple $.ajax + GET ... and displays data on Sucess. How can I check the number of data returned?

Comment: @Dranreb i recommend you post a new question with the JS code snippet and under the JS tag. That question is different than what you are asking here.

Comment: So why wouldn't the php code know how many rows there are? It is pretty easy to get a count of rows out of a database and just check if the offset is greater than the count. Could even use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to optimize it and/or store that in session so it doesn't have to be queried every time. Seems to me the only place that would know what the end of a list is, would be the php considering it has direct access to the list.